# Не удается анимировать высоту блока pure .js

Tags: javascript, css3

элемент высоту которого нужно менять:

```html
 <div class="hotel_options">
                        <div class="hotel_level">
                            <div class="hotel_level_wrapper">
                                <div id="star1" class="level">
                                    <div class="level_number">1</div>
                                    <div class="level_picture"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="star2" class="level">
                                    <div class="level_number">2</div>
                                    <div class="level_picture"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="star3" class="level">
                                    <div class="level_number">3</div>
                                    <div class="level_picture"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="star4" class="level">
                                    <div class="level_number">4</div>
                                    <div class="level_picture"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="star5" class="level">
                                    <div class="level_number">5</div>
                                    <div class="level_picture"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkin_checkout">Заезд - Выезд</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="meal_options">
                            <div class="meal_options_wrapper">
                                <div class="meal_type">Завтрак</div>
                                <div class="meal_type"></div>
                                <div class="meal_type"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

пытаюсь анимировать изменение блока по высоте при помощи добавления и удаления классов к элементу. попробовал все что можно, анимация не работает.  изменение высоты должно происходить при нажатии на одну из кнопок-вкладок, при нажатии на другую - высота уменьшается.
       разметка управляющего блока:

```html
<div  role="group" class="btn-group tabs_for_widget">
            <button v-if="tabsEnabled.indexOf(1) !== -1" @click="tab = 1; showHotelPannel()" class="b-tabs__item search_type_button"
                    :class="{_active: tab === 1}">
<!--              <i class="fas fa-ticket-alt"></i>-->
                <span id="getEvent" class="b-tabs__text">Билеты</span>
            </button>
<!--            v-if="tabsEnabled.indexOf(2) !== -1"-->
            <button   type="button"  @click="tab = 2; showHotelPannel()" class="btn b-tabs__item search_type_button"
                     :class="{_button_active: tab === 2}">
<!--                <i class="fas fa-hotel"></i>-->
                <span class="b-tabs__text">Отели</span>
            </button>
<!--            v-if="tabsEnabled.indexOf(3) !== -1"-->
            <button   type="button"  @click="tab = 3; showHotelPannel()" class="btn b-tabs__item search_type_button"
                     :class="{_button_active: tab === 3}">
                <span class="b-tabs__text">Туры</span>
            </button>
        </div>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
.hotel_options {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
        height: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #ffffff90;
        overflow: hidden;


    }
    .hotel_options_expanded{
        transition: height 5s;
        -webkit-transition: height 3s;
        height: 71px;
    }
    .hotel_options_collapsed {
        height: 0;
        transition: height 5s;
        -webkit-transition: height 3s;
        max-height: 71px;
    }
```

```js
showHotelPannel: function() {
      var hotelElement = document.querySelectorAll('.hotel_options');
      var tab = this.tab;
      console.log(this.tab);
      hotelElement.forEach(function(element){
        if (tab === 2) {
          // element.style.height = '71px';
              element.classList.add('hotel_options_expanded');
              element.classList.remove('hotel_options_collapsed');
        } else {
          // element.style.height = '0px';
              element.classList.remove('hotel_options_expanded');
          element.classList.add('hotel_options_collapsed');
        }
      })
    },
```

Comment: высота меняется, но не работает анимация.

Comment: Вы не добавили разметку. Да и вообще, странный подход - изменения можно контролировать добавляя/удаляя только 1 класс.

Comment: Управление через добавление\удаление одного класса так же не приносит результата, как и этот дурацкий способ со вторым классом.

Comment: Пожалуйста, объедените куски кода в один работающий пример, в котором можно было бы увидеть проблему.